# Object not found When Try To Save Data From JSON Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, xampp

Thank you for opening this question.

I am building a scraper, py script scraps things, py put results in json, php read it and display them in view. when i try to choose some record to save in my database it results in error

```
Object not found!
```

that error happened for most of the data, some others are saved fine into my database.

the error is just random, I don't think there is some pattern
from what I found. Object not found issue usually related with path, route, httacess, but in my case, the path is correct (some data can be saved fine).

> What I tried to find the problem :

1. to see the pattern from data that can be stored and can't

result : no pattern, from 30 data i scrapped, only data no 3,4,5,15,16,17,21,22,23,24,27,28 and 29 worked

2. change the order of data inside JSON file that store the scrape result

result: no pattern, for some data, to whatever order a data is moved, that data is still can/cannot be saved, so an order is not affecting. sometimes order effects

3. Check Htaccess

it exists and located correctly

```
located at : C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

> My MVC Snippet if it's help.  (I'm using Codeigniter)

controller :

```
function saveProduct($URLEncoded){
        $this->load->model('modelhere');
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\selenium\scrap-product.json'), true);
        $URLdecoded=base64_decode(urldecode($URLEncoded));

        $savedData;
        //GET THE URL FROM CHOSEN DATA, THEN GET DATA THAT MATCH WITH CHOSEN DATA URL IN JSON FILE
        // DATA CONTAINS PRODUCT AND SELLER INFORMATION
         for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($json) ; $x++) { 
            if ($json[$x]['URL'] == $URLdecoded) {$savedData = $json[$x];}
         } 
        // CHECK IF SELLER EXIST IN DB      
        $result = $this->penjual_model->cekPenjualExist($savedData);

        //CHECK IF PRODUCT EXIST IN DB
        $result2 =  $this->produk_model->cekProdukExist($savedData);


        // IF !EXIST(SELLER) : SAVE THAT SELLER
        if (empty($result)){
            $this->penjual_model->tambahPenjual($savedData);            
        }

        // IF EXIST(SELLER) AND !EXIST(PRODUK) : SAVE THAT PRODUK       
        if (!empty($result) && empty($result2)){
            $this->produk_model->setDataProduk2($savedData, $result);
        }

        // IF BOTH EXIST DO NOTHING
        else if (!empty($result) && !empty($result2)){
        }

        //REDIRECT
        $this->index();

    }
```

Model :

```
function setDataProduk2($temp, $temp2){
            //isi produk    
            $uname['productname'] = $temp['productname'];
            $uname['website'] = $temp['marketplace'];
            $uname['weight'] = $temp['weight'];
            $uname['desc'] = $temp['desc'];
            $uname['URL'] = $temp['URL'];
            $uname['idseller'] = $temp2['idSeller'];
            $this->db->insert('produk', $uname); 

        }
```

View  :

```
//it's the submit button that encode and sends selected product url to controller
$i=0;
if(isset($data)){
foreach ($data as $list){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'
        <a  class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href='.base_url('product_controller/saveProduct/'.urlencode(base64_encode($list['URL']))).'>save</button>'.
        "</td>";

        $i++;
}
}
?>
```

> example of URL that worked fine :

raw URL :

```
https://mywebsite/p/sitepath/sitepath2/sitepath3/6epkxb-chocolate-aura?from=omnisearch&product_owner=normal_seller&search%5Bkeywords%5D=chocolate
// i don't think that i can show the raw URL due to some reasons

encoded :
http://localhost/scraper/produk_controller/saveresult/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYnVrYWxhcGFrLmNvbS9wL3BlcmxlbmdrYXBhbi1rYW50b3IvYWxhdC10dWxpcy1rYW50b3IvbGFrYmFuLWxlbS82ZXBreGItanVhbC1sYWtiYW4tY29rbGF0LW1lcmstYXVyYT9mcm9tPW9tbmlzZWFyY2gmcHJvZHVjdF9vd25lcj1ub3JtYWxfc2VsbGVyJnNlYXJjaCU1QmtleXdvcmRzJTVEPWNva2xhdA%3D%3D
```

example of not working :

```
raw:
https://mywebsite/p/sitepath/sitepath2/sitepath3/el6k85-jual-squishy-chocolate?from=omnisearch&product_owner=normal_seller&search%5Bkeywords%5D=chocolate

encoded:
http://localhost/skripsi-scraper/produk_controller/simpanPencarian/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYnVrYWxhcGFrLmNvbS9wL2hvYmkta29sZWtzaS9tYWluYW4vbWFpbmFuLWxhaW5ueWEvZWw2azg1LWp1YWwtc3F1aXNoeS1jb2tsYXQ%2FZnJvbT1vbW5pc2VhcmNoJnByb2R1Y3Rfb3duZXI9bm9ybWFsX3NlbGxlciZzZWFyY2glNUJrZXl3b3JkcyU1RD1jb2tsYXQ%3D
```

> So, my questions are :

1. any idea what caused it and maybe the solution?
2. are there any ways to debug this ?

> My JSON file if it's help

[JSON](http://pasted.co/a1671eb5) - it has 30 row data

Comment: if you need other information or data, i will update

Comment: Your json seems valid, are you sure that all the sites mentioned within the json allows you to scrape their website? maybe they're blocking their connection from scraping tools

Comment: Hi, the sites are scraped, the JSON I provided is the result. The problem is I cannot save some data on that JSON file to database, because of object not found